# Wave equation calculation

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, gauss-law

when I have a 1 dimensional, linear wave equation:

$\Box\ \psi(t,z)=(\partial_z^2-\frac{1}{v^2}\partial_t^2)\ \psi(t,z)=0$.

$\Box$: d´Alembert operator

So linear combinations of plane waves $e^{ik(z-vt)}$ are solutions.
In case of small frequency seperations out of this finite sum, there is an integral:

$\psi(t,z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk\ b(k)\ e^{ik(z-vt)}$

with a weight funktion $b(k)$. How could we calculate this integral for $b(k)=e^-{\frac{(k-k_0)^2}{2(\Delta k)^2}}$, means for Gaussian $\Delta k$ that is concentrated around $k_0$.

Would be thankful for help!

Comment: Do you need the result or you want to learn how to solve this type of integral?

Comment: the most important thing would be to learn how to solve it. And additionally the result to see the whole process..if possible

Comment: Then maybe you should post in the math forum. I think that the result is obtained by using integration by parts and some tricks. But does a physicist really care? :)

Comment: haha, you´re right ;) I did, but no answer. Seems not to be trivial

Comment: Maybe is too trivial for the the math forum. Google has many hits about this topic.

Comment: One of them is on the math stackexcange. :)                  
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270566/how-to-calculate-the-fourier-transform-of-a-gaussian-function

Comment: There are good online integrators.

Comment: This sounds more like a straight forward math problems than a physics problem.  You see this type if integral in particle physics and QFT.  A complex contour integration method is usually taught.  Also, this may be a Gaussian wave packet but not related to Gauss-Law of electrostatics.  I'd remove that flag.

Comment: In addition to contour integration, there is also the saddle-point approximation which in general is very good.

Comment: OK I will give it a try, thanx guys!